# Запуск CUDA-программ на разных машинах

Tags: cuda

Здравствуйте!
Я в полном отчаянии...Есть программа,использующая CUDA.Есть два компьютера - домашний и рабочий.

На домашнем компе стоит видеокарта GTX 750 Ti, Win7 x64, CUDA Toolkit 7.5. Программа работает великолепно, без нареканий, без вылетов и ошибок. Запускается одновременно 8192 потока, этого вполне хватает. Драйвера для карты стоят последние, скачанные с сайта НВидии.

На рабочем компьютере стоит Win7 x64, GTX 1060, CUDA Toolkit 7.5, свежие драйвера. Программа не хочет брать более 512-ти потоков, ибо выпадает с ошибками, обычно это unspecified launch failure при попытке запуска cudaMemcpy(DeviceToHost).

Если взять GTX 1060 и вставить в мой комп, то проблем не возникает, и даже могу спокойно запустить в четыре раза больше потоков, без проблем. Друг тестировал на своём компе, у него Win10, GTX 980, результат такой же, ошибки и завершение программы.

В чём может быть проблема с работой программы на других компьютерах? Тестировалась релизная версия, все библиотеки лежат там, где им и положено. Да даже если собрать новый проект на других компах - результат не меняется, ошибка на ошибке и завершение программы. Может ли так случиться, что мой домашний компьютер заколдован доброй феей?

Comment: Пригласите фею и на работу тоже как нибудь вечером после работы ;)

Comment: С другими версиями cuda toolkit я бы попробовал - 7.0, 8.0

Comment: Пробовал собирать под 8.0 на GTX 980,безрезультатно.

Comment: Итак, стало понятнее,но не совсем. Я нашёл,что проблема возникает,если взять значение переменной,которая используется как шаг в программе,0.05 (до этого стояло 0.01), то на рабочем компьютере всё прекрасно работает. Почему на рабочем компьютере программа может работать только со значением этой переменной большим 0.05, а дома спокойно может работать со значением 0.01?Домашний комп слабее рабочего по всем параметрам...

Answer (score 2):

Какие рантайм библиотеки используются для запуска программы на рабочем компе cudart64_хх? 
Вообще тебе лучше собрать версию с 8 тулкитом и подсовывать cudart64_80 при выполнении программы на рабочем компе, так как только с 8 тулкита появился полная поддержка паскаля. 
В другом случае ты можешь обратиться к этой статье:
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pascal-compatibility-guide/index.html#verifying-pascal-compatibility-using-cuda-7-5

> CUDA applications built using CUDA Toolkit versions 2.1 through 7.5
>   are compatible with Pascal as long as they are built to include PTX
>   versions of their kernels. To test that PTX JIT is working for your
>   application, you can do the following: Download and install the latest
>   driver from http://www.nvidia.com/drivers. Set the environment
>   variable CUDA_FORCE_PTX_JIT=1. Launch your application. When starting
>   a CUDA application for the first time with the above environment flag,
>   the CUDA driver will JIT-compile the PTX for each CUDA kernel that is
>   used into native cubin code.
>
> If you set the environment variable above and then launch your program
>   and it works properly, then you have successfully verified Pascal
>   compatibility.
>
> Note: Be sure to unset the CUDA_FORCE_PTX_JIT environment variable
>   when you are done testing.

P.s. И да не забудь указать sm_61 при сборке GPU кода, чтобы на паскале побежало.

Comment: На домашнем компе cudart32/64_75,на работе последний более-менее рабочий вариант под восьмым тулкитом собран.

Comment: Поставь CUDA toolkit 8 на домашний комп, при сборке проекта добавь sm_61 архитектуру. После сборки у тебя есть исполнительный файл *.exe, рядом с ним положи библиотеки от 8 toolkit'a. И вот это все копируй на рабочий комп и пробуй запускать.